# Plugins relative urls

Tags: wordpress, relative-path

I am trying to make the urls of the plugin relative.But I couldnt find a solution used a filter plugins_url to make thaem relative

```
add_filter('plugins_url','mk_urls_relative');
function mk_urls_relative($url){
   $replace_urls = site_url();
   return str_replace($replace_urls, '', $url ); 
}
```

Thnks

Comment: Read the codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url

Comment: *Why* do you want to do that?